# How can I implement a function with multiple call signatures?

Tags: typescript

I want to constrain my function.

Given a certain literal type as input, only a certain template literal type should be returned as output for two of the input cases.

For example given the input `"rain"` I want the output `"umbrella_foo"`.

To address this I created this overloaded function:

```
type Options = "rain" | "sun" | "wind" | "snow";

type OverloadedFunction = {
  (option: 'rain'): `umbrella_${string}`;
  (option: 'sun'): `shorts_${string}`;
  (option: Options): string;
};

const myFunctionFoo: OverloadedFunction = (options: Options) => {
  if (options === "rain") {
    return 'umbrella_foo';
  }
  if (options === "sun") {
    return 'shorts_foo';
  }
  return 'anything'
}
```

`OverloadedFunction` seems alright but unfortunately hovering over `myFunctionFoo` I see the TypeScript error:

```
Type '(options: Options) => "umbrella_foo" | "shorts_foo" | "anything"' is not assignable to type 'OverloadedFunction'.
  Type '"umbrella_foo" | "shorts_foo" | "anything"' is not assignable to type '`umbrella_${string}`'.
    Type '"shorts_foo"' is not assignable to type '`umbrella_${string}`'.(2322)
```

Why does TypeScript want to assign `"shorts_foo"` to something of type `umbrella_${string}`?

Somehow, TypeScript ignores the if/else conditional. It's no different with a switch/case block.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFARAJwEMEUcoAfXNAVxPNwHdiATUinNFJenAbgCg+oSLABuEPABskBJhCYAxGgGNEqLFADefKFAAUSeMhQAuKAHJCxMwEpTAAyoBbAEZ4IEiQQD6AEg1pgPGIAcwBfO34dfUNUUzNqFBt7NAALJDxgNF9-QJDwyL0DVRNYGPRbKACglGD+UP4+JVQAqEcQRRQVI3kkJFMYMUlpWQVlYvVo4rR+srRrLAA+TW0oBAAzQtmsTGx8IhJ5rR0dN2AqPBRzJ1d3Ty813rMC0JX1zant3YScQ5WTiDOF3MqXSmXuj2eK1O50uZgIKBAwBSITMfFCQA) of the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) or [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types).  Rather, it's about how the compiler checks assignability for [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) types which have multiple [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33482](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33482) for a canonical answer.

---

To make the issue clear, let me rewrite your example without any literals or template literals:

```
type OverloadedFunction = {
  (x: string): string;
  (x: number): number;
};

const arrowFn: OverloadedFunction // error!
  //  ~~~~~~~ <-- Type '(x: string | number) => string | number' 
  // is not assignable to type 'OverloadedFunction'.
  = (x: string | number) => x;
```

Here we have the same problem. The compiler is not able to see that the initializer for `arrowFn` conforms to `OverloadedFunction`.  The value `(x: string | number) => x` is inferred to be of type `(x: string | number) => string | number`, which is too wide to be assignable to `OverloadedFunction`.

Indeed, if all you knew about a function was that it accepts `string | number` and outputs `string | number`, you wouldn't be safe using it where an `OverloadedFunction` is needed.  For example:

```
const sameProblem: OverloadedFunction // error!
  //  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '(x: string | number) => string | number' 
  // is not assignable to type 'OverloadedFunction'.
  = (x: string | number) => Math.random() ? String() : Number();
```

In this case the error is a good one, right? The function just randomly returns a `string` or a `number` without consulting the input value at all, which is not what an `OverloadedFunction` does.

According to [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35338#issuecomment-558867975) on a duplicate of microsoft/TypeScript#33482,

> TypeScript can't analyze the function body to determine which codepaths get taken during certain overload cases, so it can only look at the overall inferred return type, which is indeed wider than the specified return type. It isn't possible to write this assignment pattern without a type assertion in at least one location.

Such analysis is not impossible to implement, but it would make compiler performance worse; the time to type check functions would apparently scale by the square of the number of call signatures (cf [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235#issuecomment-271447268) on a related issue in GitHub), and so the cost of doing so is greater than the benefit.

If you want to assign a function expression to an overloaded function type and you run into this problem, you'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that everything is fine:

```
const arrowFnAssert
  = ((x: string | number) => x) as OverloadedFunction;
```

---

But do note that arrow functions are not generally the way people implement overloads.  As you've seen, the compiler tends to give false positives because it is too cautious to allow what turns out to be a safe implementation.

Instead, people generally implement overloads via *function statements*, which are checked more loosely:

```
// call signatures
function statementFn(x: string): string;
function statementFn(x: number): number;

// implementation
function statementFn(x: string | number) {
  return x; // no error
}

const reassigned: OverloadedFunction =
  statementFn; // okay
```

Now there's no error.  This doesn't actually mean it's checked thoroughly, though. That would still be too expensive for the compiler.  It's just that for overloaded function statements, the compiler errs on the side of false negatives, and so it *fails* to catch errors like this:

```
function oops(x: string): string;
function oops(x: number): number;
function oops(x: string | number) {
  return Math.random() ? String() : Number(); // no error
```

For *that* issue, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235), where again it is explained that the "proper" check is prohibitively expensive.

---

Either way, the compiler is unable to really determine what is and is not a safe implementation for an overloaded function.  You'll have to use a type assertion or an overloaded function statement if you want to proceed without a compiler error, and in either case you need to be careful to do the correct check yourself because the compiler is unable to.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAkFwTwBwUwAgPIDcYCcA2B7AhgExrgGICuAdgMZgCWmpcAvHAN7BxwAUAHgFxwDOYVFVIBzAJS8BQ0QG5WHHnFLEAtgCM0Epao2o5AXznBytAXGypUmAO6FSvZGix4CJCtVpwA9F7horqACE8j5sAH4RkWFwADwAtHFwACrQ8ADkXJKCwiJwAD7a6poMAHz82aL5hbppcCG+VHxKmGDmfHxUIqTYaujwYJhwkLBwaY4YOPhEZJQ0pGkAdPKMmeXSuQXKRahipXCcRiakZnzYKjAACla9MCoOKBMu0+5z3r7+mEH14VG-0fGJFIjDKKKQ5KpbXS7ehlMGVTY6NC1b6NZqtbDtTrdG5DQbDdLjZxTNyzWiLZYKLLrCGInZ7ACy2DAAAsFqhsKRcJgVOxdgB+OAAZQqIl5cF4ADlabzDqZ0ZYbHYAILtNBgCnsVZwjbVYow-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)

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer but is an overloaded function statement like `oops` not entirely useless? In `oops`' body, even `if (typeof x === 'string') { return 6; }` is possible. Hence, overloading the function from my original question will not give me any benefit, or will it?
One might say that the function overload serves as documentation of the function's intent, but one might also see it as misleading because other developers who are not that proficient in TS might believe that it's actually type checking what it should... I'm torn between keeping and removing it.

Comment: Both the function statement and the arrow function have the problem that the body isn’t fully type checked properly.  One yields false negatives while the other yields false positives, and I suppose it depends which one you think is worse as to which one you think is relatively useless.  Type assertions also result in false negatives, so an arrow function overload implementation with type assertions is similar to an overloaded function statement in terms of safety.  I don’t know which one to recommend, but I can say from experience that overloaded function statements are more common.

Comment: After a re-read of your comment: I think overloaded functions are much more useful for *callers* than they are for *implementers*.  As an implementer you bear the burden of verifying type safety because the compiler kind of gives up.  If you implement it properly, though, then a caller will benefit from the different call signatures.  Whether this is worth it to you depends on your use cases I guess.

Comment: Thanks! That makes complete sense. As a caller, the IDE will directly show me the different possible function signatures!