# Typescript generic key of type string or number

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

So I have these types:

```
type car = {
    id: number;
    horsePower?: number;
    date: Date;
};

type book = {
    id: string;
    title?: string;
    date: Date;
};
```

Now I want to create a generic function that takes a parameter like `horsePower` or `title` and searches in a list of `cars` or `books` for duplicates. So the search parameter and the id can differ in types, so `string|number` is possible for both.

But the passed in key and value needs to be of the same type, either `string` or `number`.

I tried this approach:

```
constructor() {
  const carList: Array<car> = [{ id: 111, horsePower: 1337 }];
  this.ifAlreadyExists(carList, 'horsePower', 1337, 'id', 100);

  const bookList: Array<book> = [{ id: '222', title: 'Title 1' }];
  this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, 'title', 'Title 1', 'id', '200');
}

ifAlreadyExists<T, H extends keyof T, K extends keyof T>(
  data: Array<T>,
  key: Extract<keyof T, string | number>,
  value: Extract<T[K], string | number>,
  idKey: H,
  idValue: T[H]
): boolean {
  if (typeof value === 'string' && typeof key === 'string') {
    return (
      data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item[idKey] !== idValue &&
          item[key] &&
          value &&
          item[key].trim().toLowerCase() ===
          value.trim().toLowerCase()
      ).length === 0
    );
  } else {
    return (
      data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item[idKey] !== idValue &&
          item[key] &&
          value &&
          item[key] === value
      ).length === 0
    );
  }
}
```

Repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-11-playground-forked-y9ku0?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

But when I want to do type specific calls, it fails:

```
Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string | number> & string]'.ts(2339)
```

How can I tell typescript, that the passed `key` matches the type of the passed `value`. So then `item[key]` could only be of the types `string` or `number`

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).

Comment: You may be surprised to realize that `item[key]` may in fact be a `number`?  [Observe...](https://tsplay.dev/w6XxRm).  The compiler is technically right to complain.  Presumably you should either just assume this won't happen [and use a type assertion](https://tsplay.dev/WPx1LW) or [be extra careful](https://tsplay.dev/w8K4pW) (not sure what you want to do if that's violated) or something else.  I'm happy to write these up as an answer; if you still have unmet needs, though, please [edit] the question to specify them.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I edited the question with greater detail. I'd like to specify the parameters to my needs instead of handling unexpected type violations

Comment: Well does [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3aBEw) meet your needs?  This prevents someone from calling the function with `string | number`, but it still needs a type assertion because the compiler cannot really understand that `item[key]` and `value` are *correlated* to each other; see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). Let me know if I can write this up as an answer or if you need something else.

Comment: Almost. I forgot to mention that there could also be keys of other types in the data array. Like `date: Date;`. I added it to the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnXEVW)

Comment: Oops, that was something like a typo in my code (I forgot to use `H` in the call signatures).  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6XGEm) work for you?  If so I'll write it up as an answer. If there are still unsatisfied use cases let me know and I'll try to address them.

Comment: No problem :) Yes this works as expected. But I forgot that sometimes my keys are undefined. Could you also give me an example for [this](https://tsplay.dev/N53jVW) screnario? If this is matched you get the bounty :)

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgexm)? Just make sure to update the example code in the question (so that the answer doesn't look like it's introducing that `undefined` out of nowhere) and I'll be happy to write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks you can write that up as an answer. I also tried that for the `idKey`, so `id` could also be undefined. But I couldn't get it to work. Maybe you could give an quick example how to handle undefined PropertyKeys, so I can solve it myself

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbG18W)?  I'm mostly just adding `Partial<>` around object types or `| undefined` to property value types.

Comment: Almost, you can now input an `idKey` that is not a property of the data array like `qweweqwe`. [example](https://tsplay.dev/WYB5vw)

Comment: That's what an optional property would mean, though... the compiler sees `{a: string}` as assignable both to and from `{a: string, b?: string}` (which is unsound but very useful) so that you can pass a value like `{a: "hello"}`, inferred as type `{a: string}` to a place that expects a `{a: string, b?: string}`.  The compiler doesn't really care that `{a: string}` doesn't have a *declared* `b` property, and if it did, things would break a lot of real world code. So when you say `"qweweqwe"` is an optional key for `carList`, the compiler is happy with that.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to proceed here, it kind of seems like the scope is getting away from the original question and while I do like me some bounties I don't want to go down a rabbit hole.  Like, if I come up with some more complicated way to deal with this particular issue with *declared* vs *undeclared* optional keys for `idKey`, it would really distract from the `key`/`value` issue that it seems the question is really about.  Maybe that would be an interesting thing to do, but possibly in a separate question?

Comment: Yes I know what you mean. I take a look at my models this weekend and if I need further help, then I open up a new question. Just post your [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099752/typescript-generic-key-of-type-string-or-number?noredirect=1#comment124099448_70099752) as an answer. Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a constraint that when you call `ifAlreadyExists()`, you need  the type of `value` and the type of `data[n][key]` (for numeric `n`) need to either both be assignable to `string` or both be assignable to `number`.

The easiest way to enforce this  for *callers* is probably to make it an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method with two call signatures, one for each possibility:

```
// call signatures

ifAlreadyExists<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number>>>, 
  key: K, value: string,
  idKey: H, idValue: string | number
): boolean;

ifAlreadyExists<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, number>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number>>>, 
  key: K, value: number,
  idKey: H, idValue: string | number
): boolean;
```

The first call signature handles the `string` case and the second signature handles the `number` case.  Splitting into overloads prevents weird situations where you have values of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `string | number`:

```
  this.ifAlreadyExists(
    [{ a: Math.random() < 0 ? "hey" : 7 }], // error
    // ~ <-- you want a compiler error here
    "a", "hey", "a", 100
  );
```

In that example, the inferred type of `data[0].a` is something like `string | number`, and if you accept that, you will end up accepting a case where `value` is a `string` while `data[0].a` turns out to be a `number`, and the check `typeof value === 'string'` is not a sufficient check.  In our discussion in comments you indicated that you really don't want to have to check both `typeof value` and `typeof item[key]` for each `item` element of `data`, so it's probably best to prevent the method from being called that way.

---

Anyway, you can see that the call signatures are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in two type parameters: `K` corresponds to the property key passed in as `key`, and `H` corresponds to the property key passed in as `idKey`.  From these parameters, we can express the type of `data` as:

```
Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number>>>
```

(for the first call signature) which means that it will accept any parameter that is an array of elements having an optional `string`-valued property at key `K` (this changes to `number` for the second call signature) and an optional `string`-or-`number`-valued property at key `H`.  This frees us from having to deal with a third type parameter `T` corresponding to the type of `data`. We *could* have done this, but it's not necessary (at least with the use cases presented in the question).

Let's make sure that callers are happy:

```
  const carList: Array<Car> = [{ id: 111, horsePower: 1337, date: new Date() }];
  this.ifAlreadyExists(carList, 'horsePower', 1337, 'id', 100);

  const bookList: Array<Book> = [{ id: '222', title: 'Title 1', date: new Date() }];
  this.ifAlreadyExists(bookList, 'title', 'Title 1', 'id', '200');
```

Those compile fine, so it looks good.

---

So the call signatures are fine.  Now we need the implementation:

```
ifAlreadyExists(
  data: Array<Record<string, string | number | undefined>>,
  key: string, value: string | number, idKey: string, idValue: string | number
) {

  if (typeof value === 'string' && typeof key === 'string') {
    return (
      data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item[idKey] !== idValue &&
          item[key] &&
          value &&
          (item[key] as string).trim().toLowerCase() ===
          value.trim().toLowerCase())
    ).length === 0;
  } else {
    return (
      data.filter(
        (item) =>
          item[idKey] !== idValue &&
          item[key] &&
          value &&
          item[key] === value
      ).length === 0
    );
  }
}
```

Overload implementations are checked more loosely by the compiler than call signatures, mostly because it can't really afford to do the kind of analysis necessary to do it properly and it errs on the side of looseness; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70089922/2887218) for details.

So for `data` we can widen the type all the way to `Array<Record<string, string | number | undefined>` and the compiler will happily let us index into every element of `data` with any key we want, and read or write any value of a `string`, `number`, or `undefined` type, or any union of those.  This makes most of the implementation code compile without error, except for:

```
item[key].trim().toLowerCase() // error!
```

as you had in your original question.  And that's because the compiler still thinks `item[key]` could be `number` even though `typeof value === 'string'`.  Yes, we prevented that from happening by having those two call signatures, but the implementation doesn't know about the call signatures.  It only knows that `data` holds elements of bags of `string | number | undefined` properties and has no idea that this the type of the property at key `key` will be the same as that of `value`.  And there's really no great way to convince the compiler of this; it would be easier to check `typeof item[key]` than it would be to rewrite the code so that the compiler would just *know* it ahead of time. In other words: `value` is of a union type, and `item[key]` is of a union type, and the compiler treats them as independent when they are correlated, and correlated union types are not really supported by the compiler; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for a relevant issue.

The easiest thing to do here by far is what I normally do in the face of correlated unions; use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just *tell* the compiler the type of `item[key]` and move on:

```
(item[key] as string).trim().toLowerCase() // okay
```

Both the type assertion and the overload implementation allow you to write code the compiler can't verify as type safe.  The fact that there are no compiler warnings is therefore a convenience and not a guarantee of type safety.  When you write overload implementations or type assertions, you are taking some of the responsibility of checking type safety away from the compiler.  There's really no other good option in this case, since the compiler is unable to handle this responsibility.  But it means you should be especially careful and double check that what you are doing is safe.  Obviously you could have written

```
(item[key] as number).toFixed(2).toLowerCase() // also okay
```

and the compiler would be just as happy to allow it, even though you are going to have a problem at runtime.  So be careful!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgGYCuw8ALgJYD2wJttAFAHTsDaAHgDRICeAXQBcSDlEoAnasADmfYKTAAjCJMEBKPPkJIAvjqKV+MZAGEQkpAF5tRItQAmAflGKVagNy6iAC1qSUBAACrQA7mquSO6qkt72SI4glBCiACLJEPH63rrGpkgAQkwA1jZ29k5REtJy2UbUlBgQ1VIysvWJmemZ2Xq5RPAYIFBQSACCMDBmtGAw9BDAlNo+SPD0NaRUAcxaBAmDG8vokgAy1BKi45KSIPwAPBaSAHzlHLhITqIAjL98-oEQuE1D8AMyggDsfCSKTcEDCSAyKV2+kEnSMvgurGoxHGGEkEBAjn4AFEuBdKFBmCdzhI+AByAFBUIRST0vjfcFQpD0pzspDfAAMgo0AwO62AEiQylKtMoVxud3uxVoJVetnen0conpACZ9fyaE1UjyACqNZoC-kwk3AeGIzIovRo1YYrE4vEEomk8kSKky1VyhlG5r8+nm41Whl8hm64X00WGA6UTFQbG4-GE4lkilU132TUgUQAWWSvlYt2AjlmKPuSEFSGcSAARL4IPxm0hRBDUXwAPR9pBqSQBfNEAdIAB+SHuAFpZwJaKQkGEQEskCA1rMYNRmlZhwEkG2CWOWyBm3xW+2L2eb0LBfnE0miAZVh7M96c377gBpIdcFIqzGYIR1MSRjB-ds+AACX-QDHGA0C1Ag9tnmYfMYSLCZFQeYJLBoTB7gAJQgdZJEcX8+BqdpnleAAyJA8PA6hCJIsiKOgqi2jkJAAB9oiUWJaOePgSnbUQfz4AA3TBSBNai5B4fMnEg-hRE4rUADVZPk7jZD4gSPEkDRRADZo1zFBwMy9bNfUpX84MWBDGKQ8D+FUmDHKAlzaDAlD+DQjDkiw65blw-CWIwYjSICCjJMMoT6MYiLWJi8j7g0hT9P4mI1GE0TxKQeKZIwOS3EEtQlIOLVVPUvgnG00rdNqbKErUEzpSYczgEsz5rKzH1c3Q6rMIVMLovY+4sq4lqDNyqx+PIRwIGIGQIEcWiqoOMS1KQaakBKsq9r0uaKskerHFq46Wouxqjqy06jNWPZn0qYgkGYfIIFod7DuQawAZ5LL6SQOiGK+n6kB2mxAfpYGXuqogCUoUhJAYYbEaITDWFWjAUkkDHMaIZhGggMAtGsZ5T2q0mwA4FT20EJAAEJAYanTQbo6mDlpjgdqZsHuYSP7OaF+wSZSOn+Y3MYso0Vg2jAXYFdoU5gUkCwghRAHrDFog-oV6QlflyhVfVzWIF2DRT3l5o5BTGHbEFdF9CHDAggqarkdR9Huex3H8cJomJbJimqaJnnJfpy7GZZtnHDu5BBYjhJeel5OU-1jmM8ztPY51g6dO523FlkB2C4fTHE2qgwElr-QkztBFJmmbcFiWXZcj0IA)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tuple to store both the key and value arguments.

```ts
type car = {
    id: number;
    horsePower?: number;
    date: Date;
};

type book = {
    id: string;
    title?: string;
    date: Date;
};

function foo([key, value]: ["horsePower", number] | ["title", string]) {

    if (key === "horsePower") {
        console.log(value); // will always be a number
    }

    if (key === "title") {
        console.log(value); // will always be a string
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only run it you may:

```
data.filter(
#here-->  (item:any) =>
          item[idKey] !== idValue &&
          item[key] &&
          value &&
          item[key].trim().toLowerCase() ===
          value.trim().toLowerCase()
      ).length === 0
```

but I don't think that 'any' is the best solution

Comment: That does remove the error shown in the IDE but at runtime it could happen that `item[key]` is of the type `number` and then an error gets thrown. `item[key].trim()` is not possible on a number