# TypeScript: How to write a function conforming to an intersection of function types?

Tags: typescript, types, intersection

It seems to me that in TypeScript if one wants to capture the type of a unary function that when given a number returns a boolean but when given a string returns a bigint, one could do that quite aptly with the type

```
type InterFunc = ((x: number) => boolean) & ((y: string) => bigint)
```

But then, how does one actually supply an instance of this type? The following attempt fails

```
let myFunc: InterFunc
myFunc = (a: number | string) => {
    if (typeof a === 'number') return true
    if (typeof a === 'string') return BigInt(a.length)
}
```

with the error

```
error TS2322: Type '(a: number | string) => bigint | true' is not assignable to type 'InterFunc'.
  Type '(a: number | string) => bigint | true' is not assignable to type '(x: number) => boolean'.
    Type 'bigint | true' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

But if the above won't work, using conditions that I thought TypeScript took as type guards  for number and string, respectively, how could I possibly write a function conforming to the InterFunc type?

Comment: Function intersections are equivalent to functions with multiple call signatures, aka, [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  TS is bad about type checking overloads.  You can write a function statement and the compiler will be too loose, or a function expression and it will be too strict.  The "too loose" alternative lets you do what you're looking for like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wORo6W), but it's not safe.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70089922/2887218) unless I'm missing something. Let me know.

Comment: I did try to search carefully for this question but I can see why I didn't hit that other question because it "seems" to be about template type literals. But your answer there is _precisely_ an answer to this question. So should (a) I just delete this question (which I assume I can do) or (b) since this question is stated more generically than that one, and therefore may be easier for future questioners to find, you put a super-brief answer just pointing to your answer of the other one, which I will accept? I am fine either way, just let me know. Thanks, jcalz!

Comment: You should leave this question open and it can be marked as a duplicate of the other one, so that people who find this question will see the answer to the other one.  If you delete it, searchers will never find it.  Duplicates can be found by searching, though

Comment: Oh, ok. Since it is now closed, there can't be an answer to this one, but I am making one last comment to make it clear to any future visitors that it is the _answer_ to the referred duplicate question that is precisely the answer to this question, even though the questions may look superficially distinct.